# Connect preorder predecessor with its successor in a binary search tree

Tags: c, tree

Actually in an interview i was asked to write a code through which every node in a binary search tree is having a extra pointer namely "next" we have to connect this pointer  of every node to its pre order successor ,can any one suggest me the code as i was not able to do so. the tree nodes has above structure :-

```
 struct node {
        int data ;
        struct node *left,*right;
        struct node *next; //this pointer should point to pre order successor 
        };
```

thank you .

Cracked the the solution thanks to you guys ,below is the whole code written in c :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
        int data;
        struct node *left,*right,*next;
};

struct node* getNode(int data)
{
        struct node* temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
        temp->data=data;
        return temp;
}

void insert(struct node**root,int data)
{
    if(!*root)
    {
        *root=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        (*root)->left=(*root)->right=NULL;
        (*root)->data=data;
    }
    else if(data<(*root)->data)
        insert(&((*root)->left),data);
    else if(data>(*root)->data)
        insert(&((*root)->right),data);
}

struct node* preorderSuccessor(struct node* root,struct node* p)
{
    int top,i;
    struct node *arr[20];
    if(!root || !p)
        return NULL;
    if(p->left)
        return p->left;
    if(p->right)
        return p->right;
    top=-1;
    while(root->data!=p->data)
    {
        arr[++top]=root;
        if(p->data<root->data)
            root=root->left;
        else
            root=root->right;
    }
    for(i=top;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(arr[i]->right)
        {
            if(p!=arr[i]->right)
                return arr[i]->right;
        }
        p=arr[i];
    }
    return NULL;

}

void connect(struct node* parent,struct node *r)
{
        if(r)
        {       connect(parent ,r->left);    
                r->next = preorderSuccessor(parent,r);
                connect(parent,r->right);
        }
}


int main()
{
        struct node* root=NULL,*temp=NULL;
        int arr[]={10,11,2,3,9,8,4,5},size,i;
        size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

        for(i=0;i<size;i++) 
          insert(&root,arr[i]);
        connect(root,root);
        struct node *ptr = root;
        while(ptr){
          // -1 is printed if there is no successor
          printf("Next of %d is %d \n", ptr->data, ptr->next? ptr->next->data: -1);
          ptr = ptr->next;
        }


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?

Comment: So traverse the tree with preorder traversal and connect. What's the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no coding service.

Comment: @Olaf sir i totally understand your point,i don't have the code which i tried at that time else would have pasted it for correction.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson actually every node in the tree has an extra pointer namely "next",in every node this pointer should point to its pre order predecessor. i.e if  1 2 3 4 is the preorder traversal  then 1's next should point to 2 and so on

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry sir but i'm not able to figure out how to connect it .

Comment: To clarify the question, please edit the question instead of posting comments. Especially fix this "Pres order successor". To get an answer, please described what your idea was.

Comment: @MartinZabel will keep your words in mind from next time

Comment: thank you guys @Olaf,@Andrew Williamson,@EugeneSh,@Martin Zabel :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eugene said: *So traverse the tree with preorder traversal and connect.* To do that, you need to know which node, if any, you visited last.

You can do that with the usual recursive approach by passing a reference to the previous node. This must be the address of a variable that is valid throughout the recursion, because the previous node is not necessarily closer to the root. You could use a global variable, but a variable created in a wrapper function may be better:

```
void connect_r(struct node *node, struct node **whence)
{
    if (node) {
        if (*whence) (*whence)->next = node;
        *whence = node;

        connect_r(node->left, whence);
        connect_r(node->right, whence);
    }
}

void connect(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *p = NULL;

    connect_r(head, &p);
    if (p) p->next = NULL;
}
```

The pointer `p` in `connect`, whose address is passed to the recursive function `connect_r` holds the node whose `next` pointer should be updated next. The update doesn't happen on the first visited node. and the `next` member of the last visited node must explicitly be set to `NULL` after the recursion.

Alternatively, you can connect the nodes iteratively by using a stack:

```
void connect(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *p = NULL;
    struct node **prev = &p;

    struct node *stack[32];    // To do: Prevent overflow
    size_t nstack = 0;

    if (head) stack[nstack++] = head;

    while (nstack) {
        struct node *node = stack[--nstack];

        *prev = node;
        prev = &node->next;

        if (node->right) stack[nstack++] = node->right;
        if (node->left) stack[nstack++] = node->left;
    }

    *prev = NULL;
}
```

The connected `next` pointers are a snapshot of the current tree. Insertions, deletions and rearrangements of nodes will render the `next` chain invalid. (But it can be made valid again by calling `connect` provided that the tree's left and right links are consistent.)

Comment: In general an iterative approach is preferable, as it has deterministic CPU stack behaviour. For this example you do not need a manual stack. If you reach a leave just move up the newly estaqblish up-link chain, provided the `next` (`up` would be a better name for tree-nodes) pointer is properly initialised to a _null pointer_). Anyway, the correct way is to set the parent-link when a node is inserted, not afterwards.